# Debugging rspec with ruby1.9 and netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rspec

How can I debug rspec specs with an IDE? specifically I'm using the following:
 * Ubuntu 10.04
 * ruby 1.9.2-dev built with rvm
 * rails3-beta4
 * NetBeans 6.9

I have installed the *ruby-debug19* and the *ruby-debug-ide91* gems, but NetBeans doesn't recognize my fast-debugger. Besides trying to debug a spec in NetBeans gives the following error:

```
ruby 1.9.2 debugger listens on port 35461
--- !ruby/exception:NoMethodError 
message: undefined method `critical=' for Thread:Class
--- 
- /home/mping/devel/netbeans-6.9/ruby/ruby/debug-commons-0.9.5/classic-debug.rb:269:in `trace_off'
- /home/mping/devel/netbeans-6.9/ruby/ruby/debug-commons-0.9.5/classic-debug.rb:279:in `block in read_command_loop'
- /home/mping/devel/netbeans-6.9/ruby/ruby/debug-commons-0.9.5/classic-debug.rb:275:in `loop'
- /home/mping/devel/netbeans-6.9/ruby/ruby/debug-commons-0.9.5/classic-debug.rb:275:in `read_command_loop'
- /home/mping/devel/netbeans-6.9/ruby/ruby/debug-commons-0.9.5/classic-debug.rb:330:in `block in <class:DC_DEBUGGER__>'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same error here, but for debugging wirh

- Ubuntu 10.10 32Bit
- Aptana Studio 2
- Ruby 1.9.2p0 via rvm 1.0.14
- Rails 3.0.0
- ruby-debug-base19 0.11.24
- ruby-debug-ide19 0.4.12